# is there a way on vim to show all column numbers in the current buffer line?

Tags: vim

It would be very nice to have an option that would show all the column numbers of the current line or maybe of all the buffer, so I could know where exactly to navigate. Is there such an  option or do i have to program it myself (nooo XD)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`:h 'statusline'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27statusline%27)

It is as easy as defining exactly what you what to see printed. e.g.

```
" RulerStr() comes from http://www.vanhemert.co.uk/vim/vimacros/ruler2.vim
function! RulerStr()
  let columns = &columns
  let inc = 0
  let str = ""
  while (inc < columns)
    let inc10 = inc / 10 + 1
    let buffer = "."
    if (inc10 > 9)
      let buffer = ""
    endif
    let str .= "....+..." . buffer . inc10
    let inc += 10
  endwhile
  let str = strpart(str, 0, columns)
  return str
endfunction

let s:saved_stl = {}
function! s:ToggleRuler()
  let buf = bufnr('%')
  if has_key(s:saved_stl, buf)
    let &l:stl = s:saved_stl[buf]
    unlet s:saved_stl[buf]
  else
    let s:saved_stl[buf] = &l:stl
    setlocal stl=%{RulerStr()}
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> µ :<c-u>call <sid>ToggleRuler()<cr>
```

A bit optimized version (that requires [method](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#method) support from Vim 8.1.1878) would be:

```
function! s:precompute_ruler(columns) abort
  let nb = a:columns / 10
  let res = range(1,nb)->map({_,n -> printf('....+% 5d', n)->tr(' ', '.')})->join('')
  return res
endfunction

let s:ruler = s:precompute_ruler(500) " should be more than enough
function! RulerStr2() abort
  return s:ruler[:&columns-1]
endfunction

let s:saved_stl = get(s:, 'saved_stl', {})
function! s:ToggleRuler() abort
  let buf = bufnr('%')
  if has_key(s:saved_stl, buf)
    let &l:stl = s:saved_stl[buf]
    unlet s:saved_stl[buf]
  else
    let s:saved_stl[buf] = &l:stl
    setlocal stl=%{RulerStr2()}
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> µ :<c-u>call <sid>ToggleRuler()<cr>
```

Comment: nice, ill give it a try and gonna come back with the outcome

Comment: Looking for the same solution except in Visual Studio 2017. Does anyone have any leads?

Comment: How to use this code? How to call "µ" to show the ruler? I changed "µ" to "mm", removed "silent" mode, pressed "mm" and got error while running the code.

Comment: @AntonSamokat
I've just tested the code and it still works fine 12y later with vim 9.1.125 -- even with `mm` as a trigger (which I'd never use as I'm a heavy user of [_marks_](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#mark)). Could you copy the error you're observing? Could you be running a version of Vim compiler without [`+statusline`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%2Bstatusline) support?

Answer (score 5):

You can use "set ruler". It will show the line number and column position at the bottom.

Comment: i want to see displayed all column numbers, not just the current one :D

Comment: Ohh...Never heard of that, I don't know this will help or not, but u can use "<num>|" command to move your cursor to a particular col. For eg: '8|' will move the cursor to 8th column. I don't know how to display the column numbers.